# Static routes in route-eth0 ignored

Tags: centos, ip, route

Why might route-eth0 be ignored but route-eth1 not?  Might be because eth0 is using DHCP and eth1 is statically-configured?

I have some static routes configured in

```
[16:20:06][root@zserver2:/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts]$ ls -al ro*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 104 Dec  6 15:49 route-eth0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 106 Dec  6 15:49 route-eth1
```

When I do a `service network restart` the routes for eth1 are activated but NOT those for eth0.

An `ifup eth0` also ignores them, but an `ifup-routes eth0` is just fine. What's the best way of getting it activated?

```
[16:18:36][root@zserver2:/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts]$ service network restart
Shutting down interface eth0:  Device state: 3 (disconnected)
                                                           [  OK  ]
Shutting down interface eth1:  Device state: 3 (disconnected)
                                                           [  OK  ]
Shutting down loopback interface:                          [  OK  ]
Bringing up loopback interface:                            [  OK  ]
Bringing up interface eth0:  Active connection state: activating
Active connection path: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/28
state: activated
Connection activated
                                                           [  OK  ]
Bringing up interface eth1:  Active connection state: activated
Active connection path: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/29
                                                           [  OK  ]
```

#### route info

```
[16:18:50][root@zserver2:/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts]$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.15.10   192.168.15.11   255.255.255.255 UGH   1      0        0 eth1
192.168.15.11   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth1
192.168.15.11   192.168.15.91   255.255.255.255 UGH   1      0        0 eth1
192.168.15.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.15.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

#### ifup eth0 manually

```
[16:19:03][root@zserver2:/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts]$ ifup eth0
Active connection state: activating
Active connection path: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/30
state: activated
Connection activated
```

#### route info

```
[16:19:35][root@zserver2:/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts]$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.15.10   192.168.15.11   255.255.255.255 UGH   1      0        0 eth1
192.168.15.11   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth1
192.168.15.11   192.168.15.91   255.255.255.255 UGH   1      0        0 eth1
192.168.15.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.15.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

#### ifup-routes eth0 manually

```
[16:19:56][root@zserver2:/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts]$ ./ifup-routes eth0
[16:20:00][root@zserver2:/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts]$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.15.1    192.168.15.90   255.255.255.255 UGH   5      0        0 eth0
192.168.15.10   192.168.15.11   255.255.255.255 UGH   1      0        0 eth1
192.168.15.10   192.168.15.1    255.255.255.255 UGH   5      0        0 eth0
192.168.15.11   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth1
192.168.15.11   192.168.15.91   255.255.255.255 UGH   1      0        0 eth1
192.168.15.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.15.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

Config files are:

*ifcfg-eth0*

```
[16:30:26][root@zserver2:/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts]$ cat ifcfg-eth0
DEVICE=eth0
TYPE=Ethernet
UUID=76ef8242-9e22-4a29-93f3-a142d1460c87
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6INIT=no
NAME="System eth0"
HWADDR=00:25:90:86:71:E0
PEERDNS=yes
PEERROUTES=yes
LAST_CONNECT=1386361279
```

*ifcfg-eth1*

```
[16:30:35][root@zserver2:/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts]$ cat ifcfg-eth1
DEVICE=eth1
TYPE=Ethernet
UUID=647f66bd-67b2-4e9a-b5a5-4280ad677b9a
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6INIT=no
NAME="System eth1"
IPADDR=192.168.15.91
PREFIX=32
HWADDR=00:25:90:86:71:E1
LAST_CONNECT=1386361279
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is likely timing. Among other things, the `ifup` script does this:

- puts `eth0` in an "up" state
- starts `dhclient` to obtain an IP address
- loads static routes from `route-eth0`

The problem is that `ifup` doesn't wait for `dhclient` to get an IP address before trying to load your static routes, and the kernel won't install a route for an interface without an IP address configured on it.

If you must use DHCP, one solution is to let `dhclient` add the routes for you. Per the manpage for [dhclient-script(8)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/dhclient-script) from CentOS 6.5:

> Immediately after dhclient brings an interface UP with a new IP address, subnet mask, and routes, in the REBOOT/BOUND states, it will check for the existence of an executable* **/etc/dhcp/dhclient-up-hooks** script, and source it if found. This script can handle DHCP options in the environment that are not handled by default. A per-interface **/etc/dhcp/dhclient-${IF}-up-hooks** script will override the generic script and be sourced when interface $IF has been brought up.

You should be able to make this work by creating a `/etc/dhcp/dhclient-eth0-up-hooks` script containing the following:

```
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup-routes eth0
```

Answer (score 0):

That would be my conclusion as well. DHCP i/f's get their routing info from the DHCP server, so these files are ignored, when that's the case.

You should be able to go through NetworkManager and add addtional routes through the UI.

#### Example

[image: ss of nm1]

[image: ss of nm2]

[image: ss of nm3]

Comment: Thanks @slm, but I tried adding through the Network Manager and it just put the same data in route-eth0.

Comment: @IanWorthington - perhaps you're getting tripped up by the issues discussed in this forum thread? http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=219788

Comment: You mean NM not really updating the file?  It does, I checked it with different value.  Also noted later that it carefully blew away my device value... Won't be using that again.

Comment: @IanWorthington - yes the updates of the files. So the changes show up then?

Comment: Changes I make through the NM gui show up in the files, yes.

And just found that ifup calls nmcli if NM is active and never bothers with ifpost which would call ifeth/ifroutes/...